# SSIS Lookup transformation including whitespace

Tags: sql-server, ssis, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

For some reason, the SSIS Lookup transformation seems to be checking the cache for a NCHAR(128) value instead of a NVARCHAR(128) value.  This results in a whole bunch of appended whitespace on the value being looked up and causes the lookup to fail to find a match.

On the Lookup transformation, I configured it to have No Cache so that it always goes to the database so I could trace with SQL Profiler and see what it was looking up.  This is what it captured (notice the whitespace ending at the single quote on the second last line - requires horizontal scrolling):

```
exec sp_executesql N'
 select * 
 from (
  SELECT SurrogateKey, NaturalKey, SomeInt
  FROM Dim_SomeDimensionTable
 ) [refTable] 
 where [refTable].[NaturalKey] = @P1 
  and [refTable].[SomeInt] = @P2'
,N'@P1 nchar(128)
,@P2 smallint'
,N'VALUE                                                                                                                           '
,8
```

Here's the destination table's schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dim_SomeDimensionTable] (
[SurrogateKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[NaturalKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[SomeInt] [smallint] NOT NULL
)
```

What I am trying to figure out is why SSIS is checking the NaturalKey value as NCHAR(128) and how I can get it to perform the lookup as NVARCHAR(128) without the whitespace.

Things I've tried:

- I have LTRIM() and RTRIM() on the SQL Server source query.
- Before the Lookup, I have used a Derived Column transformation to add a new column with the original value TRIM()'d (this trimmed column is the one I'm passing to the Lookup transformation).
- Before and after the Lookup, I multicasted the rows and sent them to a unicode Flat File Destination and there was no white space in either case.
- Before the lookup, I looked at the metadata on the data flow path and it shows the value as having data type DT_WSTR with length 128.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference.

You need to look elsewhere for the source of your problem (perhaps the column has a case sensitive collation for example).

Trailing white space is only significant to SQL Server in `LIKE` comparisons, not `=` comparisons [as documented here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626).

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   , General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE
>   and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and
>   'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.
>
> The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate...

You can also easily see this by running the below.

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dim_SomeDimensionTable] (
[SurrogateKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[NaturalKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[SomeInt] [smallint] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Dim_SomeDimensionTable] VALUES ('VALUE',8)

exec sp_executesql N'
 select * 
 from (
  SELECT SurrogateKey, NaturalKey, SomeInt
  FROM Dim_SomeDimensionTable
 ) [refTable] 
 where [refTable].[NaturalKey] = @P1 
  and [refTable].[SomeInt] = @P2'
,N'@P1 nchar(128)
,@P2 smallint'
,N'VALUE                                                                                                                           '
,8
```

Which returns the single row